# Another word for "wedding"

Tags: word-usage, word-request

There is an term 'wedding', when you put your signature and it becomes official. But what is the right term for a religious act when two swear to be faithful, to love each other e t.c. in front of the God and a priest in church? Is there such term in English speaking countries? I mean, in some countries young people prefer to "marry" only in church and not to sign any documents officially.
I heard about such terms as 'crowning' or even 'church wedding' but I'm not sure it is correct to use any of them.

Comment: In the US, the couple needs a civil marriage license even if the wedding ceremony is conducted in a religious setting and/or by a religious minister.

Answer (score 3):

There is the word [*Nuptial*](https://www.google.co.uk/search?num=40&safe=active&q=define+nuptial) which can be used either as a noun or adjective.

As a noun, Nuptials refers to the ceremony of marriage, wherever it may take place.

As an adjective, [*nuptial*](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=nuptial&t=crmtb01) describes things related to the marriage.

Answer (score 2):

It might depend not only on regional customs but religious customs as well. The term that I am familiar with in AmE is *church wedding* as you suggested:

> [church wedding](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/church-wedding)
>   a wedding ceremony performed in a church and having a religious rather than civil content
>   (Collins Dictionary)

*Wedding* by itself can be somewhat broad. It does not necessarily mean signing a marriage license and becoming "official". It really depends on the context, taking regional, religious, and personal factors into consideration.

As for the "official" one, as far as I know, that's a *civil marriage* or a *civil wedding*.

> - [civil wedding](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/wedding)
>     American English
>     a wedding that is not performed by a religious leader
>     (Longman Dictionary)
> - [civil marraige](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/civil-marriage)
>     a marriage performed by a justice of the peace, judge, or similar official, not by a clergyman
>     (Collins Dictionary)